# Can I bring cooked meat into The Netherlands?

Tags: international-travel, food-and-drink, netherlands

I will travel to The Netherlands in November.

Am I allow to bring cooked meat in the plastic bag and seal it into The Netherlands? I will bring about 500 grams (1/2 kg) of cooked meat. Please let me know if am I allowed to bring it.

Comment: Where are you coming from? If it's elsewhere in the EU, then no problem. Otherwise, then I'd expect it to be retained by customs

Comment: Is it freshly cooked or preserved in a can or something?

Answer (score 4):

## Across the EU border

Here are the rules regarding meat products:

> ## General Rules for Meat and Meat Products
>
> Imports of fresh meat and meat products into the EU are subject to veterinary certification which is based on the recognition of the competent authority of the non-EU country by the Directorate-General for Health and Food Safety. This formal recognition of the reliability of the competent authority is a pre-requisite for the country to be eligible and authorised to export such products to the EU. Legally legitimate and adequately empowered authorities in the exporting country must ensure credible inspection and controls throughout the production chain, which cover all relevant aspects of hygiene, animal health and public
>   health.
>
> All bilateral negotiations and other relevant dialogue concerning imports of meat and meat products must be undertaken by the national competent (veterinary) authority. All other interested parties and private businesses wishing to export to the EU should contact their competent authority which in turn will communicate with the European Commission.
>
> ## Inspection of meat and meat products at the EU border
>
> Imports of meat or meat products must enter the EU via an approved Border Inspection Post of the EU under the authority of an official veterinarian in the EU Member State in question.
>
> Each consignment is subject to a systematic documentary check, identity check and, as appropriate, a physical check. The frequency of physical checks depends on the risk profile of the product and also on the results of previous checks.
>
> Consignments which are found not to be compliant with EU legislation shall either be destroyed or, under certain conditions, re-dispatched within 60 days.

(From [this EU document](https://ec.europa.eu/food/sites/food/files/safety/docs/ia_trade_import-cond-meat_en.pdf))

Schiphol Airport has other guidelines outlined [here](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/page/what-can-cannot-travel-with-you/).

Comment: I would summarize this answer as "No, you can't, unless you have reams of paperwork."