# Can I bring frozen baked Jamaican Patties into the Netherlands?

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, netherlands

For context, Jamaican Patties can be thought of as an empanada; baked pastries with a little meat filling (roughly like 20% to 35% meat to pastry ratio).

I know to the US, I can bring it in with no hassle, however, my main thoughts are can I bring it into the Netherlands? I have read a bit about the customs for bringing in meat products but there's so much ambiguity.

What I feel from reading that it's up to the discretion of the customs officer to believe if it is a threat or not. If it's baked and frozen, is it still allowed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bring cooked meat into The Netherlands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147556/can-i-bring-cooked-meat-into-the-netherlands)

Comment: You might want to double check the "no hassle to bring into the US" statement too.

Comment: You can't bring it into the US either: https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/Can-I-bring-meat-or-poultry-into-the-US: _"If any meat is used in preparing a product, it is prohibited."_

Comment: @user2705196: sounds like it's no hassle if you don't get caught. But the same applies to anything you bring over the border.

Comment: Bringing meat products into the US is definitely not no-hassle. Even a sandwich with meat for personal consumption during travel is verboten.

Answer (score 18):

According to [the Dutch government's website](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/travel-abroad/bringing-items-netherlands):

> If you are travelling from a country outside the EU, you cannot bring meat and dairy products (including eggs) into the Netherlands. You may bring in up to 20 kilos of fish, however. But the fish cannot be an endangered species. It must always have been cleaned and the innards must have been removed.

So there is no ambiguity and your import will not be allowed.

Comment: so the fact that it contains just a bit of cooked meat makes it not allowed?

Comment: @penguin As the answer states, *meat* is not allowed. Whether baked or frozen makes no difference without the relevant health declaration. See also this link from the duplicate question https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/animal_products_foodstuffs/animal_products_and_foodstuffs

Comment: @Traveller whether baked or frozen or incorporated into a pastry filling.  But if you keep reading then you start to see exceptions: that sweets containing animal products are excepted, for example, and that it may be possible to import meat with a health certificate.

Comment: @phoog The only exceptions for any type of meat coming from outside the EU (and six other countries in Europe) are infant food and (medical) pet food. See paragraph 4.1 and 4.2 bullet a and b in [this document](https://www.nvwa.nl/binaries/nvwa/documenten/import/veterinair/nvwa-import-veterinair/algemeen/alim07-producten-voor-persoonlijke-consumptie/ALIM07+Producten+voor+persoonlijke+consumptie+versie+1.1.7.pdf) (in Dutch). Any not recognizable 'meat' in sweets would refer to gelatin and colorings and the like, not cooked meat in a pastry

Comment: @Berend gelatin and I suppose butter and eggs (since the ban is on meat and dairy products including eggs).  But the exception for food with a certificate and subject to inspection on arrival would apply to the Jamaican patties, even if going through this bureaucracy isn't likely to be justified for most people wanting to import Jamaican patties for personal reasons.

Comment: @penguin : **So there is no ambiguity and your import will not be allowed.**